# Trying to update value in firebase database while listening for changes on another place (Cloud Functions)

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to update the count of the participants in a field in firebase realtime database.
My database looks like this:
**root**
|_course
|       |_Course1
|            |_descr: "some text"
|            |_lect: "someUID"
|_groups
|        |_Course1
|            |_Group1
|                 |_current: 5
|                 |_others -//-
|_participation
|        |_Course1
|            |_someUID: "Group1"
So now I'm trying to listen for writings on participation/Course1/someUID and when some record shows up I want to update the 'current' field to 6 in groups/Course1/Group1.
So far I've come with:

```
exports.afterGroupJoined = functions.database.ref('/participation/{courseId}/{uid}').onWrite((change, context) => {
    const writtenContent = change.after.val(); // groupId
    const courseId = context.params.courseId;
    const uid = context.auth ? context.auth.uid : null;

    admin.database().ref('/groups/' + courseId + '/' + writtenContent).once('value').then(snapshot => {
        const count = snapshot.val();
        const current = count+1;
        console.log('User ' + uid + ' joined group ' + writtenContent + ' in course ' + courseId);
        const promise1 = admin.database().ref('/groups/' + courseId + '/' + writtenContent + '/current').set(parseInt(current));
        return Promise.all([promise1]);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
});
```

But what I get is a new child in groups/Course1/Group1 named 'null' with child 'current' having value '0':
**root**
|_groups
|        |_Course1
|            |_Group1
|            |    |_current: 5
|            |    |_others -//-
|            |_null
|                 |_current: 0
The value of 'current' should've been 6, but I get a new child.
This is from the log:

```
User fNhAVZUo9QeSbYt0TwBIQmL2mYq1 joined group Group1 in course Course1
Error: Reference.set failed: First argument contains NaN in property 'groups.Course1.Group1.current' at validateFirebaseData
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It looks like `count` is not a number, either because it has no value or because it's not a numeric value. You might want to `console.log(count)` after reading it from `snapshot.val()`.

Comment: [object Object]

Comment: So that explains: an `Object` is not a number, so you can't add `1` to it. I'm guessing you need `const count = snapshot.val().current;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're reading this JSON:

```
"Group1": {
  "current": 5
}
```

Which means you need this code to get the actual count:

```
const count = snapshot.val().current;
```

But you're not using anything else from the group, so you might as well just read the count itself. The `Promise.all()` call also seems unneeded, since you have only one promise. So the entire block could be:

```
let ref = admin.database().ref('/groups/' + courseId + '/' + writtenContent+'/current');
ref.once('value').then(snapshot => {
    const count = snapshot.val();
    return ref.set(count+1);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Finally: this approach is susceptible to race conditions if multiple users run the above at almost the same time. You might want to consider [using a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#section-transactions).